# Updating title of textbox in a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a jQuery plugin that allows me to add in-line labels to my form's textboxes by using `Title="Full Name"` the only problem is that I have coded a javascript translator that translates everything on the page to English, French, or Spanish. I need the title to be updated too.

I've tried using `document.getElementById`, but that's not working. I'm guessing because it's inside the form. Here's a copy of the html that makes up my form.

```
    <form id="signupform" method="post" action="login.php">
            <div class="field"><input type="text" class="box" id="name" name="fullname" title="Full Name"></div>
            <div class="field"><input type="email" class="box" id="email" name="useremail" title="Email Address"></div>
            <div class="field"><input type="password" class="box" id="pass" name="password" title="Password"></div>
            <div class="field"><input type="password" class="box" id="confirmpass" name="confirm" title="Confirm Password"></div>
            <div id="lowersignuparea"> 
            <table width="306" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td><span id="signuperror"><?php echo $signuperror ?></span></td>
            <td width="87"><span><input type="submit" class="signupbutton" id="signupbtn" value="Sign Up" style="cursor:pointer;"></span></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
  </form>
```

Any ideas on how to change the title of the textbox through JavaScript?

Thanks.
-Ryan

Comment: `$('yourelement').attr('title','whatever you want')`

Comment: jQuery is easy: `$('#name').attr('title', 'New title for name');`

Comment: Now this might sound stupid, but I don't really understand jQuery. (Like I've never really used it). So do I need to put this in it's own .js file, or can I put this is in an existing javascript file with JAVASCRIPT already in it?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. That's why I am making sure.

Comment: Just reference it using the script tag in your html. :) http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js

Comment: This should be a very simple fix. (Without using jQuery.) I'm trying to change the title attribute of the textbox (which is inside a form.) All I need to know is how to find that in javascript. For example. If I wanted to change the text of a div tag in html with javascript I would. HTML: `<div id="hello">Hi</div>` Script `document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = "Hello";`. This would change the text "Hi" in the 'Hello' div tag to "Hello". I could easily change that .innerHTML to .title if it wasn't inside the form! So. How do I "getelementbyid" when it's in a form? (code still above)

Answer (score 0):

You can set title value using javascript like this.

```
document.getElementById("elementid").setAttribute("title", "my new title");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your code in ready event as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form input').each(function(){
            var translated = translateYourTitlte($(this).attr('title'));
            $(this).attr('title', translated);
        });
    });
</script>
```

you should provide plugin name which you are using for display tooltip.